# Как в Clion кастомизировать Toolbar?

Tags: intellij-idea, clion

Можно ли кастомизировать toolbar в Clion, когда он расположен на одной линии с путем (для примера приложил скриншот)? Я знаю, что можно кастомизировать его, когда выбрано отображение View->Appearance->Toolbar, но это не то, что меня интересует.

[image: file]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: ну @aleksandrbarakin, ну это не серьезно. Ну прочитайте вопрос

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вы что - бот?

Comment: а если правой кнопкой мышки кликнуть по этому тулбару, там нет ничего?

Comment: @KoVadim, к сожалению нет

Comment: вот с этого начните https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/customize-actions-menus-and-toolbars.html#show-hide

Comment: @KoVadim, по всей видимости так сделать нельзя...

Comment: Ну значит надо переходить на нормальные редакторы

Comment: @KoVadim, например?

Comment: Vim/nvim, emacs, vscode. Хорошо настроенные под себя помогут перейти на новый уровень